# Android Studio's Terminal is garbled in win7

Tags: android, git, terminal

My gitconfig is like this:

```
i18n.commitencoding=utf-8
i18n.logoutputencoding=utf-8
gui.encoding=utf-8
```

and My git for window shows chinese language well. But the terminal in Android Studio is still garbled.
[image]
the terminal is like this when the log contains chinese:[image]

What's more, I use git for window replace the Terminal's git. But the terminal is still grabled:
[image]